# Adding the <s:if> condition in my jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

Here, I am creating a jsp where I am getting the `actionId` from the database. Here, I want to add the `<s:if>` condition tag and check for particular values.

```
 <td  style="font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;" align="center" width="50px">
     <s:property value="actionId"/>
     <s:if test="#request.dtls=='1'">testing</s:if>
     <s:iterator  value="#request.dtls" status="dtl">
     <div class="form-input">
        <s:property value="actionId"/>
     </div>
     </s:iterator>
 </td>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is s tag is same as c??

Comment: What is the `#request.dtls`? You try to compare it with string and latter you try to iterate it.

Comment: Post Action code too.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What's the type?

Answer (score 0):

The `#request.dtls` should be a collection.

```
<s:if test="#request.dtls.contains('1')">testing</s:if>
<s:iterator value="#request.dtls" status="dtl">
 <s:if test= "top == '1'">
  <div class="form-input">
   <s:property value="actionId"/>
  </div>
 </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```